# Total expectation with Lebesgue integral

Tags: probability, integration, conditional-expectation

I need to prove the total expectation theorem using the Lebesgue integration only. I have seen the proof in some forums and some probability books, but they use the usual integration encountered in the calculus based probability books. I want to prove it using the Lebesgue integration. This is the proof that I need to express using the Lebesgue integral

$E[E[X|Y]]$ = $\int ^\infty _{-\infty} E[X|Y=y] \times f_{Y} (y) dy $
$\quad$ $\quad \quad \quad \ $= $\int^\infty _{-\infty} \int^\infty _{-\infty} xf_{X|Y=y}(x) dx f_{Y} (y) dy$
$\quad$ $\quad \quad \quad \ $= $\int^\infty _{-\infty} \int^\infty _{-\infty} x f_{XY}(x,y) dx dy$
$\quad$ $\quad \quad \quad \ $= $\int^\infty _{-\infty} x \int^\infty _{-\infty} f_{XY} (x,y) dy dx$
$\quad$ $\quad \quad \quad \ $= $\int^\infty _{-\infty} xf_{X}(x) dx$
$\quad$ $\quad \quad \quad \ $= $E[X]$

Comment: Very carefully...

Comment: What is the "total expectation theorem"???

Comment: it is the expectation of the conditional expectation. it basically states that we can find the expectation of a random variable by finding the expectation of the conditional expectation of this random variable  by conditioning on another random variable

Comment: In general you cannot assume that $X$ has a conditional density given $Y$ as in the alleged proof in your question. Now the proof for the general case depends on how you define the conditional expectation. But  under the usual definition of the conditional expectation, which is that $\tilde{X} = \mathsf{E}[X\mid Y]$ is the $\sigma(Y)$-measurable random variable satisfying $$\forall A\in\sigma(Y)\,:\quad\mathsf{E}[X\mathbf{1}_A]=\mathsf{E}[\tilde{X}\mathbf{1}_A],$$ You can simply plug $A=\Omega$ to obtain the proof.

Comment: Using the usual definition of the conditional expectation, how can I link it to the conditional distribution to be used in the proof? and for the expectation using the Lebesgue integral, $E[X] = \int X dP$ , how can I use this expectation in the proof, I mean how can I integrate with respect to x and to y, because at the beginning, I am finding the expectation of the conditional expectation with respect to y, so I am integrating with respect to y , then I find the conditional expectation so I am integrating with respect to x . How can I express this using the Lebesgue integral? I